# app freezes when i try to get data from string stuct?

Tags: c, string

i just recently asked a question and got help but i have another problem with my custom c string.  everything compiles fine but when i try to get something it freezes, or it could be when i delete it.  what am i doing wrong? heres my code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "String.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  String *some_string = String_New("hello");
  printf("%s\n", String_CharPtr(some_string));
  String_Delete(some_string);
  return 0;
}
```

String.h

```
#ifndef _STRING_H
#define _STRING_H

typedef struct String String;

extern String *String_New(char */*basic_string*/);
extern void String_Delete(String */*string*/);
extern char *String_CharPtr(String */*string*/);
extern unsigned int String_GetLength(String */*string*/);
extern unsigned int String_GetSize(String */*string*/);

#endif
```

and finally:

String.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#include "String.h"

struct String {
  char *basic_string;
  unsigned int length;
};

String *String_New(char *basic_string) {
  String *temp = NULL;
  temp->length = strlen(basic_string);
  temp->basic_string = (char *) malloc(temp->length + 1);
  strcpy(temp->basic_string, basic_string);
  return temp;
}

void String_Delete(String *string) {
  free(string->basic_string);
  string->basic_string = NULL;
}

char *String_CharPtr(String *string) {
  return string->basic_string;
}

unsigned int String_GetLength(String *string) {
  return string->length;
}

unsigned int String_GetSize(String *string) {
  return string->length + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String *temp = NULL;
temp->length = strlen(basic_string);
```

You haven't allocated memory for `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: you are correctly managing the memory for the character buffer, however you have forgotten about managing memory for the String structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Change part of your code to this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
String *String_New(char *basic_string) {
    String *temp = calloc (1, sizeof (struct String));
    temp->length = strlen (basic_string);
    temp->basic_string = strdup (basic_string);
    return temp;
}

void String_Delete(String *string) {
    free(string->basic_string);
    free (string);
}
```